# Usar css customizado (rails e windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Boa tarde,

Sou iniciante em rails e estou tentando colocar no projeto o frontend que tenho aqui de outro site. O HTML, css e o javascript já está todo pronto. Então gerei um controller com o nome de Public com todas as views (menus do frontend, home, contato, etc). 
Peguei depois o css e coloquei dentro de assets/stylesheets. Depois peguei os arquivos js e coloquei na pasta assets/javascripts. Fiz então um layout novo, public.html.erb. 
Nele, tento chamar o css customizado e não consigo. Já tentei editando o manifesto colocando o seu nome e nada mudou. Quando chamo lá na view usando:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'app', media: 'all' %>
```

ou

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Sempre recebo a mensagem: ExecJS::ProgramError in Public#nomedaminhaview

app.css é o nome do meu css. Como eu uso um css próprio em um aplicativo rails no windows?

Answer (score -1):

No seu 'assets/stylesheets/application.css' você deve ter

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

E no seu 'views/layout/application.html.erb'

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Isso ja importa todos os arquivos 'css' presentes na pasta 'stylesheets'